# Explain python cycle with lambdas, please

Tags: python, lambda, xlsx, cycle

i need to edit code for my needs, but unluckily i don't have a choice to rewrite from zero, so i must understand what is this, because deadline is in 11 hours. halp a junior find his job

```
    if text and segment:
        if "Office" in segment:
            if True in list(map(lambda x: x in text, _classes[_classB][0])):
                return "Класс Б"
        if "Warehouse" in segment:
            if True in list(map(lambda x: x in text, _classes[_classB][0])) or \
                    True in list(map(lambda x: x in text and True in [w not in text for w in _classes[_classA][0]], 
                        _classes[_classB][1])):

                return "Class B"    
        return ""
    return ""
```

may you eplain what the hell is

```
 True in list(map(lambda x: x in text and True in [w not in text for w in _classes[_classA][0]],_classes[_classB][1])):
```

or something like "unlambda"? big thanks

UPD: i need to add a rule: "if landsize is >9000 then ..." where landsize in another column"

Comment: It's horrendous code is what it is. Without context, I really don't think we can be too much help here sorry and even with it, that's unnecessarily complex. You have my sympathies :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 True in list(map(lambda x: x in text and True in [w not in text for w in _classes[_classA][0]],_classes[_classB][1])):
```

This is an absolute nightmare of code, so let's break it down.

```
True in list(map(...))
```

The `map()` function will return a map of objects based on some conversion function and an input. `list()` will convert it into a list.

```
lambda x: x in text and True in [w not in text for w in _classes[_classA][0]],_classes[_classB][1]
```

We can take the lambda out and turn it into a function:

```py
# globals variables to make our lives easier. Bad practice but obviously they don't
# care about that.
text = ...
_classes = ...

def mylambda(x):
  """
  Checks that x exists in text and some class doesn't appear in text.
  """
  classA0 = _classes[_classA][0]
  classInText= w not in text for w in classA0
  return x in text and True in classInText
```

Now, we can simplify it down:

```
list(map(mylambda, _classes[_classB][1])):
```

This statement will return a list of booleans.

```
True in list(map(mylambda, _classes[_classB][1])):
```

If, for any value in `_classes[_classB][1]`, that value exists in `text` and some value in `_classes[_classA][0]` doesn't exist in `text`, this will return True.

Now that that's over, please burn this code and never speak of it again.

Answer (score 5):

Okay, so first let's reformat it to get a better point of view:

```
True in list(map(
    lambda x: (
        x in text 
        and True in [
            w not in text
            for w in _classes[_classA][0]
        ],
    _classes[_classB][1]
))
```

Well it still looks like madness, but luckily we can simplify further:

- `in` and `not in` are going to give `True` or `False` but so instead of checking `True in ...` we can do `any(...)`,
- the inner list comprehension `[...]` is independent of the outer map, so we can refactor it out,
- since the `x in text` and the following `w` condition are `and`'ed, we can pull the `w` condition in front to shortcut in case it is `False`

So we obtain:

```
w_condition = any(w not in text for w in _classes[_classA][0])
result = w_condition and any(x in text for x in _classes[_classB][1])
```

Basically this seems to check that the `text` contains not all of `_classes[_classA][0]` and at least one of `_classes[_classB][1]`. Why it does that is up to you to judge.

Comment: +1 This is almost exactly how I analyzed it. I also split up the two comprehensions and switched the `any(not ...)` for `all(...)`: `x_result = any(x in text for x in _classes[_classB][1]); w_result = all(w in text for w in _classes[_classA][0]); result = x_result and w_result`

Comment: Whoops, `any(not ...)` is not the same as `all(...)`

Answer (score 0):

The following line:

```
True in list(map(lambda x: x in text and True in [w not in text for w in _classes[_classA][0]],_classes[_classB][1])):
  # do smth
```

can be rewritten as:

```
array2 = []
for x in _classes[_classB][1]:
  array1 = []
  for w in _classes[_classA][0]:
    if w not in text:
      array1.append(True)
    else
      array1.append(False)
  if x in text and True in array1:
    array2.append(True)
  else:
    array2.append(False)
if True in array2:
  # do smth
```

which can become:

```
condition1Met = False
for x in _classes[_classB][1]:
  condition2Met = False
  for w in _classes[_classA][0]:
    if w not in text:
      condition2Met = True
      break
  if x in text and condition2Met:
    condition1Met = True
    break
if condition1Met:
  # do smth
```

As I do not know your context, it is impossible for me to name the variables better, but I hope this is more manageable.